# Fail to run sp_prepare over ADODB from Visual Basic

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

I can't get the handle value to pass to sp_execute. If I use the SQL code directly with Management Studio I succeed:

```
Declare @handle Integer
exec sp_prepare @handle OUTPUT, N'@year int', N'SELECT * from Sales.CreditCard where ExpYear=@year';

select @handle

exec sp_execute @handle, 2007
exec sp_unprepare @handle
```

but when I try the following code on VB, "param3.Value" is "nothing" after the command is executed.

```
    ConnString = "DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=192.168.100.41,1433;UID=sa;PWD=<password>;DATABASE=AdventureWorks"
    'create an instance of the ADO connection
    Connection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    'Open the connection to the database
    Connection.Open(ConnString)
    Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim param1 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim param2 As ADODB.Parameter
    Dim param3 As ADODB.Parameter

    cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    cmd.ActiveConnection = Connection
    cmd.CommandText = "sp_prepare"

    param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@handle", 3, 2, 4, 0)
    param2 = cmd.CreateParameter("@params", 202, 1, 200, "@year Integer")
    param3 = cmd.CreateParameter("stmt", 202, 1, 200, "SELECT TOP 4 [CreditCardID],[CardType],[CardNumber],[ModifiedDate]  FROM [AdventureWorks].[Sales].[CreditCard] where [ExpYear] in (@year)")

    cmd.Parameters.Append(param1)
    cmd.Parameters.Append(param2)
    cmd.Parameters.Append(param3)

    cmd.Execute()

    Debug.WriteLine("handle:" & param1.Value)
```

Do you know how to make it work on VB?
The reason I run this from VB is that I need the command to be run over RPC.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change:

```
 param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@handle", 3, 2, 4, 0)
```

to

```
param1 = cmd.CreateParameter("@handle", 3, 4, 4, 0)
```

that is change in `ParameterDirection`. If you have noticed `sp_prepare` evaluates `handle` but do not display until and unless you call `select @handle`